# Calculate a float to find an Integer in Python

Tags: python

Didn't really find anything on this, so sorry if someone has already asked this question.

I am trying to divide a X value by a Y value until I get a whole integer and not a floating point number, but it keeps showing X.0 (a float) and not X (an integer).  I can't just simply convert X to an integer with int(x) as that would defeat the purpose of this.

Say for example I done 369/3, this would be 123 which is an integer...  Yet it displays it as a float (123.0), so would that mean I need to check if the number after the decimal is less than or equal to 0?  Also how would I do this?  Code is below

```
import time
x = int(369)
y = int(3)

def Calculation():
  global x
  global y
  x = x / y #keep divinding x by y until a whole integer is found
  print(x) 
  while isinstance(x,float): 
    time.sleep(0.1) #small delay to prevent crashes
    Calculation()

Calculation()
```

Is it me over thinking the obvious or can something like this not be done?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I don't really get what you are saying @user3483202, I am new to Python and pretty bad at math haha, I am just doing this to learn basics...  What do you mean by float(10)/float(5)?

Comment: Python 3.x does not use integer division by default, so if you divide 10/3, for example, you will get a float back.  Then if you divide that float by something else, you will never get an integer again, only floats.  My first comment as actually a bit misleading, because even 10/2 returns a float in Python 3

Comment: So after you do your very first division, your `while` condition will *always be true*, so you will get stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: And this is why I am here, to find a way out that loop...  As I say I am fairly new to Python, but I am struggling to think of a good way to find the value after the decimal, is there a way to find numbers after a decimal?  This way I could check if it is 0 or not and convert it to an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the modulo`%` operator. If it is 0, it means there are no remainder so it is an integer. Try the following code

```
import time
x = int(369)
y = int(3)

def Calculation():
  global x
  global y
  x = x / y #keep divinding x by y until a whole integer is found
  if(x%y == 0):
      print("it is an integer!")

  else: 
    time.sleep(0.1) #small delay to prevent crashes
    Calculation()

Calculation()
```

Comment: my bad I am new here

Answer (score 0):

Firstly if the divisor is an integer then dividing a non-integer by an integer will never result in an integer (unless we run into rounding errors and eventually get an answer of zero). In general this problem will suffer from rounding errors after a few recursions.

If you're using python 3, then you can compare the integer division (i.e. //) with the floating division result (i.e. /). Something along the lines of.

```
x = x/y
int_div = x//y
print(x)
if(x != int_div):
    time.sleep(0.1)
    Calculation(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

If all that you are confused with is to find whether the quotient of a division is an int and stop iterating once you reach an int, use the is_integer() function.

```
>>> a = 369
>>> b = 3
>>> a/b
123.0
>>> (a/b).is_integer()
True
```

Is this what you wanted?

Answer (score -1):

A type will stay a particular type until you change it.
So your loop will evaluate the same every time.

You could take a different approach such as checking

```
if int(x/y) == x/y: print(x,y)
else: 
    x=x/y
    Calculation()
```

Comment: Why not simply using `x % y == 0` ?